# Can I safely install a 90 amp main breaker in place of an existing 70 amp breaker feeding the panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Existing panel with 70 amp double pole Stab Lok main breaker feeding the panel. Can this be replaced with a 90 amp Stab Lok double pole breaker as the main?

Comment: Are you in the US or in Canada?

Comment: More information is needed to answer this question. Please post details about your panel and your electrical service.

Comment: Are you in the US or Canada? Can you post photos of the panel in question please?

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on the rating of the main panel. A bigger concern is the use of stab Lok breakers. They are fire starters and should not be used, replaced, or messed with. Post a picture of your panel for more information.

Comment: is "Plug In Circuit Breaker" the same as "stab Lok breakers"? is one safer than other?

Comment: @AndreiMihailevski    Most breakers "plug in" in some fashion or another.  Stab Lok breakers are a name brand and it's printed right on the breaker.